# Browser add-on to invoke JavaScript code on all tabs

Tags: javascript, web-browser

I've couple of hundred tabs where I want to invoke JavaScript (like clicking on the element and submitting the form).

Normally you can copy & paste the code into address bar for each tab, like:

```
javascript:document.getElementsByName('useTemplate')[0].click();
```

but even this [doesn't work](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=630733) in Chrome.

Is there any web browser extension (for Chrome or Firefox) to automate this process by executing the JavaScript code once, but for multiple tabs at the same time?

Comment: Tampermonkey or https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija?hl=en?

Comment: Tampermonkey may help, there was already the answer about it, but it was removed (probably too short), custom-javascript I think may work as well. If you post as answer with some description, it would be great.

Comment: @kenorb Do you mean [custom-javascript-for-web](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija)?

Comment: @Nemo Looks good, can it run on selected tabs at once?

Comment: @kenorb No idea! Their instructions seem to indicate that the JS is unconditionally launched for a certain domain. I ended up using Tampermonkey for my use case.